# determine east or west for GPS latitude

Tags: android, gps, maps

How can I check the phone's current location and know the latitude direction?

I know how I can get the location, but it shows like this: `Latitude: 50.9665874 Longitude: 36.998665`.

I want to know how I can check whether this latitude is east or west, like: `50.9665874 E`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Latitude and longitude will appear as positive or negative numbers (-180 to 180), so you do not need to worry about N/S/E/W. Positive latitude means it is north of the equator, while negative means south. The same with longitude based on the prime meridian where east is positive and west is negative.

Answer (score 2):

negative latitudes means South
negative longitude means West

Now for the advanced users:
Exactly at longitude 0  or latitude 0 it is neither West/East  or South/North in that case the "E" or "W" (or the S/N) indicator is omitted.